# “that which" and "did myself the honor" - June 22nd 1798 Letter by John Marshall

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Dear Sir ([Source](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=Author%3A%22Marshall%2C%20John%22&s=1111311111&r=15))
>
> Your letter to Genl Dumas was deliverd by me to his lady from whom in consequence of it I receivd during my stay in Paris the most polite & flattering attentions. She deliverd me the inclosd answer which was written in Copenhagen & forwarded to her. Having heard that Mrs Marshall is in Winchester I shall immediately set out for that place.
>   Permit me Sir to acknowledge the receipt of your very polite & obliging letter in answer to **that which** I **did myself the honor** to address to you from the Hague.

`1.` Would someone please expound the differences between "that which" and "which"? Why not "...polite & obliging letter  in answer to which I did myself the honor ..." ?

`2.` Is the expression "to do the honour to someone" or "to do someone the honour" or both? Why not the other?

`3.` [http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/do+honor+to](http://dictionary.reference.co/browse/do+honor+to) says

> I. to show respect to.
>   II. to be a credit to.

Would someone please explain how "to do honour to" engenders these meanings? Is "do" a synonym of "bestow/convey/impart" here?

`4.` How would John Marshall be doing himself the honour to address a letter to George Washington from the Hague?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *To that which* means *to the one which*. Marshall acknowledges receiving a letter from his correspondent which was a response to the one which he had sent previously.
2. *Myself* is the indirect object and *honour* the direct object in either phrasing. This follows the usual ordering rule: a ‘light’ IO (a pronoun or name, for instance) precedes the DO, a ‘heavy’ IO (longer and bearing multiple stresses) follows the DO. However: if what is in play is not the bare expression *do IO honour* but the expanded expression *do IO the honor of ...* (see 3, below), the DO is likewise heavy, and the sentence reverts to the *do IO DO* sequence:

   > The King did [<sub>IO</sub> the representatives of the three Estates] [<sub>DO</sub> the extraordinary honour of rising when they entered his presence].
3. To *do X honour* means to “perform some act which confers honour upon X”; if a specific act is named then *honour* becomes determinate, *the honour*, and the act is expressed with a preposition phrase headed by *of* and taking a gerund clause as its object: *of VERBing &c*.
4. In the elaborate courtesy which prevailed in the upper ranks of 18th-century society, merely the opportunity of addressing so distinguished a person as President (late General) Washington reflects great honour on the writer; Marshall acknowledges his temerity in conferring that honour upon himself.

Comment: It would do my head in to have to fully "unthread" the references in OP's convoluted citation, but it seems to me that this is one of those cases where ***that*** is grammatically and semantically *required* (unlike the first instance of the same word in my comment here). If it *wasn't* there, you'd have to tweak something in the words following (remove the last ***to***, perhaps?) to retain grammatical credibility - and the meaning would radically change too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perzackly. *That* is the demonstrative pronoun and the antecedent of *which*.

Comment: and yet (I *think*) you can (just about) discard the word *which* itself without trashing either the grammar or the meaning. But (again, I *think*) you can't discard *that* with such gay abandon.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes. *which* may be replaced with the 'null-relativizer', but *that* is the object of the preposition *to* and cannot be omitted.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. I'd be grateful if you could respond to my updated #2 and #3 in my OP.

Comment: @LePressentiment Does this suffice?

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply and answers. Yes, it resolves my questions instructively! Please maintain your superlative contributions and beneficence, which I'm grateful for and cherish.

Comment: @LePressentiment w~ all resp't I remain, Sr, yr most obedt  Svt :)